# Expand url django patterns

Tags: python, django, sitemap, url-pattern

i have standard django 1.4 url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
    url('^',include('events.urls')),
    url(r'^$', home, {'template_name':'index.html','mod':None}, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$',contact, {'template_name':'index.html',
        'mod':'contacto'},name='contact'),
    url('^task/(?P<task_id>[\w+-]+)',celery_tasks,name='tasks'),
)
```

I want to build my sitemap.xml leaving out some urls, for example that /task url should not appear(it makes no sense for the web spiders).
My strategy is passing all the url patterns to my Sitemap class, like this

```
from sitemaps import EventsSitemap, StaticSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'Events': CandidateSiteMap,
    'static': StaticSitemap(urlpatterns),
}
```

As you can see i´m passing the patterns to the class, so i can later filter the urls like this

```
class StaticSitemap(Sitemap):

    def __init__(self, patterns):
        self.patterns = patterns
        self._items = {}
        self._initialize()

    def _initialize(self):
        do_not_show = ['tasks']
        for p in self.patterns:
            # no dynamic urls in this class (we handle those separately)
            if not p.regex.groups:
                if getattr(p,'name',False) and p.name not in do_not_show:
                   self._items[p.name] = self._get_modification_date(p)
```

So i keep this list of do_not_show url names and thats how i filter out urls, so far so good, the problem is with included urls such as:

```
url('^',include('events.urls')),
```

I can't just iterate on self.patterns and get the included urls, i have to expand them first, thats my question, how can i do that?
How can i get a flat list of urls as if there were no included ones, all were on a single urls module.

Any recommendations to filter out urls in the sitemaps.xml would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have to answer my own question because i solved it, what i did was a little function to expand the patterns like this

```
def expand_patterns(patterns):
    new_patterns = []
    def recursive_expand(patterns):
        for p in patterns:
            if getattr(p,'url_patterns',False):
                recursive_expand(p.url_patterns)
            else:
                new_patterns.append(p)
    recursive_expand(patterns)
    return new_patterns
```

This will flatten out the urlpatterns into a single list.
So now i can use self.patterns to filter out anything in my Sitemap class :)